# Running Hadoop in full-distributed mode in a 5-machines cluster takes more time than in a single machine

Tags: algorithm, hadoop, mapreduce, cluster-computing

I am running hadoop in a cluster of 5 machines (1 master and 4 slaves). I am running a map-reduce algorithm for friends-in-common recommandation, and I am using a file with 49995 lines (or 49995 people each one followed by his friends).

The problem is that it takes more time to execute the algorithm on the cluster than on one machine !!

I don't know if this is normal because the file is not big enough (and thus the time is slower due to latency between machines) or that I must change something to run the algorithm in parallel on the different nodes, but I think this is done automatically.

Typically, running the algorithm on one machine takes this:

```
   real 3m10.044s
   user 2m53.766s
   sys  0m4.531s
```

While on the cluster it takes this time:

```
    real    3m32.727s
    user    3m10.229s
    sys 0m5.545s
```

Here is the output when I execute the start_all.sh script on the master:

```
    ubuntu@ip:/usr/local/hadoop-2.6.0$ sbin/start-all.sh 
    This script is Deprecated. Instead use start-dfs.sh and start-yarn.sh
    Starting namenodes on [master]
    master: starting namenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop-2.6.0/logs/hadoop-ubuntu-namenode-ip-172-31-37-184.out
    slave1: starting datanode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop-2.6.0/logs/hadoop-ubuntu-datanode-slave1.out
    slave2: starting datanode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop-2.6.0/logs/hadoop-ubuntu-datanode-slave2.out
    slave3: starting datanode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop-2.6.0/logs/hadoop-ubuntu-datanode-slave3.out
    slave4: starting datanode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop-2.6.0/logs/hadoop-ubuntu-datanode-slave4.out
    Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
    0.0.0.0: starting secondarynamenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop-2.6.0/logs/hadoop-ubuntu-secondarynamenode-ip-172-31-37-184.out
    starting yarn daemons
    starting resourcemanager, logging to /usr/local/hadoop-2.6.0/logs/yarn-ubuntu-resourcemanager-ip-172-31-37-184.out
    slave4: starting nodemanager, logging to /usr/local/hadoop-2.6.0/logs/yarn-ubuntu-nodemanager-slave4.out
    slave1: starting nodemanager, logging to /usr/local/hadoop-2.6.0/logs/yarn-ubuntu-nodemanager-slave1.out
    slave3: starting nodemanager, logging to /usr/local/hadoop-2.6.0/logs/yarn-ubuntu-nodemanager-slave3.out
    slave2: starting nodemanager, logging to /usr/local/hadoop-2.6.0/logs/yarn-ubuntu-nodemanager-slave2.out
```

And here is the output when I execute the stop_all.sh script:

```
   ubuntu@ip:/usr/local/hadoop-2.6.0$ sbin/stop-all.sh 
   This script is Deprecated. Instead use stop-dfs.sh and stop-yarn.sh
   Stopping namenodes on [master]
   master: stopping namenode
   slave4: no datanode to stop
   slave3: stopping datanode
   slave1: stopping datanode
   slave2: stopping datanode
   Stopping secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
   0.0.0.0: stopping secondarynamenode
   stopping yarn daemons
   stopping resourcemanager
   slave2: no nodemanager to stop
   slave3: no nodemanager to stop
   slave4: no nodemanager to stop
   slave1: no nodemanager to stop
   no proxyserver to stop
```

Thank you in advance !

Comment: (1) Are your results [statistically significant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_significance)? There is no point in analyzing anything before it is.  (2) Try creating a file much larger and see if this reoccurs. (3) Is your file distributed or a on a single machine? (If the later, and if the algorithm is relatively simple, distributing will do no good here)

Comment: @amit I updated my question to give you more details. I unfortunately can't create another file bigger than the one I have since it is not simple to generate it. I think my file is distributed on the different slaves because executing hdfs dfs -ls /user/ubuntu/Folder on the different slaves gives me the file I sent. I also executed the command hdfs dfs -put myfile.txt Folder on the master so it should be distributed on alll of them.

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason is that your file is not uploaded on the HDFS. In other words it is stored on a single machine, and all the other running machines have to get their data from that machine.
Before you run your mapreduce program. You can do the following steps:

1- Make sure that the HDFS is up and running. Open the link:
*master*:50070
Where master is the IP for the node running the namenode, and check on that link that you have all the nodes live and running. So if you have 4 datanodes you should see: datanodes (4 live).

2- Call:

> hdfs dfs -put yourfile /someFolderOnHDFS/yourfile

That way you have uploaded your input file to the HDFS and the data is now distributed among multiple nodes.

Try running your program now and see if it is faster

Best of luck